# How to prevent silver lists from rebuilding the widgets while scrolling in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-sliver

I have a customscrollview which has some slivers inside it and it contains a sliverlist, the issue I'm facing is that when i scroll down or top the list's children get rebuilt, and that what i need to avoid, thanks in advance

I need a solution without relying on keep alive mixin

Comment: Perhaps you like to use state-management solution

Comment: you cant prevent the children rebuilding. Thats how sliverlist lifecycle. Things that you need to do is to keep the state value, so that when its rebuild, the widget show the same content

Comment: you can read `destruction mitigation` here https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SliverList-class.html

Comment: i found that i need to separate the logic and benefit from the usage of state management . i surely did but i faced another issue and i will explain it right now: my idea is to insert a native add between the children of the list , and the nativeAd widget get rebuild/recreate when scrolling , my solution is to load this native ads separately by the provider and insert them inside a list then calling the children of a list , but i keen getting the same problem of rebuilding the native ad widget